# Change profile picture via mobile app

Tags: support, android-app, profile-picture

How do I change my profile picture in the Android mobile app?

Comment: Related _feature-request_: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271396/can-i-change-my-profile-photo-on-the-app

Comment: But no one replied yet :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to edit your profile in the iOS or Android apps, which means that there is no way to change your picture/avatar.

Comment: I never seeing the profile edit option in my app (stack exchange)

Comment: Yea, that's what my answer says...

Comment: `I'm pretty sure the same is valid for the Android app.` . what you mean?

Comment: It means the iOS app and Android app are the same. Thanks @Cody.

Comment: okay well. any feature request for this?

Comment: The mobile app is not feature-complete, and is not designed to be. It's a *supplement* to the website, not a replacement for it. Major tasks still need to be done using the website. So no, no feature request, and I doubt one would be fulfilled. There is only one or two people even working on the apps, and this won't be high on their agenda. No one *urgently* needs to change their profile picture. @ram

Comment: any requirements are going in stack overflow?  I can join there and I will complete this task if SO have not much resource. :P @CodyGray